# How to get list of all properties and methods of a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Is there any way to get the list of all properties of any React component. For example, in the material UI library, the badge component has the following attributes and methods:
anchorOrigin, children, content, classes, etc.

I want to get the list of attributes and methods of a React component, after importing it. For the above example, the console.log(getallProps(Badge)) will list all the possible properties of that component.

Comment: If you're lucky, they've defined Prop Types: `Badge.propTypes`.

Comment: I'd say you will be forced to instantiate a component before you can access it. If you have just `Badge`, this will be a constructor function and you won't get anything there... (except if `propTypes` has been used, as @cbr mentionned)